# jsp included page forward into another page

Tags: jsp

inside page1.jsp i included one page page2.jsp . with that i'm passing some variables.

### 1. ) page1.jsp

In page1.jsp i included one page like

```
<jsp:include page="page2.jsp">    <jsp:param name="name" value="<%=val1%>"/>    </jsp:include>
```

### 2. ) page2.jsp

In page2.jsp page, based on some conditions , i have to forward into error.jsp .

```
<jsp:forward page="error.jsp">    </jsp:forward>
```

### 3. ) error.jsp

```
<div> ERROR  </div>
```

But my case, its not redirecting into error page. please suggest any working things or any other alternative method.  In case it is not possible, please tell me why it is not possible.

Comment: Please format all code in your question correctly.

Comment: Is error.jsp in the same folder than others?

Comment: all the files are in same folder